# How does jTemplates perform?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jtemplates

I'm working on a website that I plan to have a lot of JSON/AJAX generated lists (kind of like a social networks news feed).  How does jTemplates work with this kind of situation?  Is there a better solution?

From what I can see, it looks nice, but I've seen very little documentation, and running examples.

Answer (score 2):

I've used **jQote2** which is lightning fast. See [this post](http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote2/) with performance tests.

It's a slightly refactored version of client-side templating engine written by **John Resig**.